# Как построить структуру БД для калькулятора пластиковых окон?

Tags: база-данных

Поставили задачу написать калькулятор для расчета стоимости пластиковых окон. Параметров и деталей много не знаю с чего начать.

Идея следующая. Выбираю тип окна, открывается блок с дополнительными опциями для данного параметра,опции так же могу делится на доп. опции. Подтолкните на идею как правильно все это организовать. Но чем глубже вложенность опции тем менее понятнее становится как все организовать и сгенерировать такую вот картину

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Постановка задачи сделана так себе, а вы уже хотите к структуре БД перейти.

Насколько я видел что происходит в такой конторе (заказывал остекление на протяжении нескольких лет) -- это в общем обычный магазин. То есть есть ассортимент товара. Часть товара массовая, просто учитываются по штукам -- это материал на откосы, подоконники, и прочее.

Другая часть товара штучная -- это сами окна.
На месте делается замер -- определяются точные размеры проёма (все окна разные, различия даже для одного панельного дома -- в несколько см, и эти сантиметры крайне важны, замерщик вообще главный человек в этом деле). Потом определяется как этот проём хотят застеклить -- как разделить на отдельные окна, какие створки будут открываться. Из этого уже получают *рамы*. Рама это именно рамка, в которой есть одно или несколько окон. Максимальные размеры рамы определяет производство. Выбирают профиль окна (KBE, Rehau -- в общем смотря с чем работает производство), количество стёкол. После замера и определения способа застекления звонят на производство, договариваются с ними как будет деление на рамы, и когда будет выполнен заказ. Цена вычисляется по некоторой формуле, параметры которой -- выбранный тип профиля и количество стёкол, размеры отдельных окон и способ застекления. Подозреваю, что одна формула расчёта цены не подойдёт для всех производств.

Все оговорённые параметры остекления выписываются на листочек, там же рисуются окна как у вас на рисунках -- чтобы видеть подробно какие будут рамы, окна, где и куда открываются. Этот этап я видел делают сначала от руки, а потом набирают в конструкторе чтобы в договоре было красиво.

Затем в некоторый день в город привозят ваши рамы и окна, звонят заказчику подтвердить день, в назначенный день приходят монтажники, у них на руках листок с рисунком окон + список особенностей.

В общем, автоматизируя такую контору, нужно чётко понимать эти этапы:

1. Замер и фиксирование пожеланий заказчика
2. Детализация и расчёт цены
3. Звонок на производство и утверждение конкретики, получение даты
4. Доставка рамы и монтаж

Автоматизация тут может быть нужна на этапе 2 -- когда делается расчёт цены. Тут же печатается типовой договор, плюс страничка с красиво нарисованным окном и списком примечаний -- автоматизация в виде конструктора для такой страницы. Всё остальное -- чистой воды бухгалтерия.

На вашем месте я бы отталкивался от типовых баз для организации торговли + особая часть, связанная с рамами и окнами.

Comment: Калькуляторы очень полезны и для клиентов на сайте, чтобы прицениться. Ошибки даже в +/-5% в самостоятельных замерах не сильно повлияют на конечную цену.

Comment: @KromStern тут палка о двух концах. Заказчики чаще всего выбирают "где дешевле", а в этом деле качество важнее цены -- остекление делается на десятки лет. Уровень качества калькулятором не покажешь.

Comment: Тем не менее практически все крупные компании имеют на сайте подобные калькуляторы. Вобщем я с вами согласен, ТС нужно четче определиться со своим ТЗ, пройти несколько тест-кейсов.

Comment: На самом деле мне поставили задачу написать аналог,разбираться во всем самому надо,мне даже формул расчета цен да и самих цен и что от чего зависит не дали

Comment: И дали на написание такого калькулятора 5 рабочих дней)) Если чесно я пока вообще в ступоре с чего начинать